# Suming different fields when active - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Let's say I have these fields:

```
#Lamination packeting
@api.onchange('cost_rs18', 'qty__m_18')
def total18(self):
    if self.cost_rs18 or self.qty__m_18:
        self.total_18 = self.cost_rs18 * self.qty__m_18

cost_rs18 = fields.Float("Cost Rs.")
qty__m_18 = fields.Integer("Qty")
total_18 = fields.Float(string="Total")
#Packing
@api.onchange('cost_rs19', 'qty__m_19')
def total19(self):
    if self.cost_rs19 or self.qty__m_19:
        self.total_19 = self.cost_rs19 * self.qty__m_19

cost_rs19 = fields.Float("Cost Rs.")
qty__m_19 = fields.Integer("Qty")
total_19 = fields.Float(string="Total")
#Others
@api.onchange('cost_rs20', 'qty__m_20')
def total20(self):
    if self.cost_rs20 or self.qty__m_20:
        self.total_20 = self.cost_rs20 * self.qty__m_20

cost_rs20 = fields.Float("Cost Rs.")
qty__m_20 = fields.Integer("Qty")
total_20 = fields.Float(string="Total")
```

These obviously sum up on their respective `total_n` fields.

But on the other hand, not always they should be sumed, let me explain myself.

All these 3 fields (they are actually 20 in my code), have their respective `total_n` fields which sum up every couple of `cost_rs_n` and `qty__m_n` ones.

Now I want to create a "total of totals" which should sum up all the 20 fields, this isn't difficult to figure out, but, my point is, that not always you will be suming all 20, sometimes are 12 active totals, sometimes 2, or sometimes all 20 of them.

How can I achieve this? Can I use the same logic I use on my `@api.onchange` but for all of them? knowing that not always they all will have data to sum?

**EDIT**

This is the function I'm actually using, it sums all the totals from all the actual fields I have on my model:

```
@api.onchange('total_1', 'total_2',
    'total_3', 'total_4', 'total_5', 'total_6',
    'total_7', 'total_8', 'total_9', 'total_10',
    'total_11', 'total_12', 'total_13', 'total_14',
    'total_15', 'total_16', 'total_17', 'total_18',
    'total_19', 'total_20')
def total21(self):
    if self.total_1 or self.total_2 or self.total_3 or self.total_4 or self.total_5 or self.total_6 or self.total_7 or self.total_8 or self.total_9 or self.total_10 \
    or self.total_11 or self.total_12 or self.total_13 or self.total_14 or self.total_15 or self.total_16 or self.total_17 or self.total_18 or self.total_19 or self.total_20:
        self.total_totals = self.total_1 * self.total_2 * self.total_3 * self.total_4 * self.total_5 * self.total_6 * self.total_7 * self.total_8 * self.total_9 * self.total_10 \
        * self.total_11 * self.total_12 * self.total_13 * self.total_14 * self.total_15 * self.total_16 * self.total_17 * self.total_18 * self.total_19 * self.total_20

total_totals = fields.Float(string="Total")
```

I've added the `default=0.00` to all these totals, but with no results, the `total_totals` field doesn't do anything, any ideas?

Comment: `that not always you will be suming all 20, sometimes are 12 active totals, sometimes 2, or sometimes all 20 of them.` You have to be more specific, what do you mean? When should these fields be summed ?

Comment: Hi, When any of them is filled, whether is 1 or 15 or 20

Comment: You can set default value in those fields as zero if there no value in it. then no matter how many field populated. you can sum up all the fields.

Comment: Hello mr. NeoVe,  try this, cost_rs20=fields.Float(string="Cost Rs.",default=0.00) , qty__m_20=fields.Integer(string="Qty.",default=0)

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but it's not working, I'm ging to edit my question

Comment: Edited, please, what am I doing wrong? Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is working fine. In you multiplication make sure all totals are !=0.

**EDIT**
I am not sure it is the best answer, but it will full fill your requirement, try below code.

```
@api.onchange('total_19','total_18','total_20')
def total21(self):
    total = 1
    for rec in self:
        for i in range(18,21):
            rec1 = eval('rec.total_'+str(i))
            if rec1:
                total = total * rec1
        if total !=1:
            self.total_totals=total
        else:
            self.total_totals=None
```

Comment: Thank You very much, yeah that worked, but if there is some empty total, I still want a sum for the ones which are active. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you need to add (sum) all totals or multiply each total?

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it.

Comment: Thank You very much, actually I'm using 20 fields, the 3 field was just an example, do you know how can I use it for 20 fields? I can open a new question for that though

Comment: Just pass 20 parameters in `@api.onchange` and change  `range` of for loop to (1,21). And try it...